# ¿Como sacar en listas diferentes atributos repetidos?

Tags: java

Buen día , tengo un `ArrayList` con una serie de datos:

```
 => 158 => 158=> 158=> 158=> 158=> 172=> 217=> 217=> 222 => 222=> 22 => 222
```

Como podría agrupar en una lista los números `158`, en otra lista el `172`, en otra lista los `217` y finalmente en otra lista el `222` ?.

De antemano gracias.

Comment: Disculpa, has visto alguno de los métodos de recorrer arrays que existen?

Comment: Has pensado utilizar un multiset de guava. `HashMultset.create(arrayList)` ? Ya con eso vas a tener un multiconjunto , osea cuando preguntes por 158.. puedes preguntar por las apariciones y te va a aparecer 5 veces en tu ejemplo, no tiene sentido crearse listas de numeros iguales que no representan nada.

Answer (score 1):

Por que no usas un mapa:

```
ArrayList<Integer> myList; // ... inicializacion y otros
HashMap<Integer, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<Integer, MyObject>();

for(Integer i: myList){
    myMap.put(i, myMap.get(i) + 1);
}

// esto es para recorrer el mapa
Set<Integer> keys = map.keySet();
Integer[] array = keys.toArray(new Integer[keys.size()]);

for (Integer key:array){
    System.out.println("numero: " + key + " cantidad: " + myMap.get(key));
}
```

Bueno, esta es la idea.

Answer (score 1):

Planteo dos soluciones :

1. Sí en la lista se sabe la cantidad de grupos que se obtendrá. como en este caso son cuatro listas , se crean cuatro listas para posteriormente recorrer la lista e ir añadiendo dependiendo del valor

   ```
   List<Integer> listone = new ArrayList<>();
   List<Integer> listtwo = new ArrayList<>();
   List<Integer> listthre = new ArrayList<>();
   List<Integer> listfour = new ArrayList<>();
   for (Integer item : lista) {
       switch(item){
           case 158: listone.add(item);break;
           case 172: listtwo.add(item);break;
           case 217: listthre.add(item);break;
           case 222: listfour.add(item);break;
           default: break;
       }
   }
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(listone.toArray()));
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(listtwo.toArray()));
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(listthre.toArray()));
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(listfour.toArray()));
   ```
2. Sí en la lista se desconoce la cantidad de grupos a obtener , se usaría una [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) para ir añadiendo las listas , además del valor de la lista , se haría uso de [Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/stream/Stream.html) para crear la colección  y la clase [Collectors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html) con su método [groupingBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-) para agrupar los valores

   ```
   Map<Integer, List<Integer>> grupos  = 
                lista.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(valor -> valor));
    /* Imprimir los valores y Listas  ,*/
   for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<Integer>> entry : grupos.entrySet())
   {
      System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " - " + entry.getValue() );
      /* Si se desea obtener la cantidad de elementos */
      System.out.println(" Total " + entry.getValue().toArray().length);
   }
   ```